# Do I need to apply for a visa to stay in Montenegro for a few days with a UK travel document and a BRP?

Tags: visas, uk-residents, montenegro

Do I need to apply for a visa to stay in Montenegro for a few days with a UK-issued 1951 UN Convention Travel Document and a biometric residence permit?

Comment: What type of UK travel document? For completeness, what is your citizenship?

Comment: I hold The convertion of 28 July 1951 and a leave to remain UK brp which expires in 9years. I am a refugee in the UK. Thank you

Comment: You can check on the [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/) website

Comment: Thank you, I’ve checked but I can’t really see the the right answers. If anyone know or know where I could get this information please get back to me. Thanks again.

Comment: You just need to input the details of your proposed trip, for ‘document held’ scroll through the options until you find *Travel Document Convention 1951*. I don’t know your citizenship so I can’t complete it. Or you can try [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&country=/ME)

Comment: @Traveller the nationality is irrelevant.  Fortunately, IATA takes this into account by offering "Stateless Persons and Refugees" as an option in the nationality list.